# Why javascript continues after I close my android app?

Tags: javascript, android, infinite-loop

I made an android app that shows an internal html with javascript in a `webview`. The javascript has an infinite loop to update the view once each minute.

The problem is that after I close my app with the back button, the javascript continues its infinite loop... Why is this happening and how can I prevent this?

Thanks!
L.

Comment: "close the app with the back button" ... the back button doesn't close apps on any Android device I've ever used.

Comment: maybe disable the javascript of the webview in the onPause method and re-enable in the onResume.

Comment: @Pointy: That depends on the app, not on the device.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit yes I guess that's true, but that's still my point - the app has to decide to stop and then do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening

Because you did not stop the loop. It will keep going until Android terminates the process.

> how can I prevent this?

Stop the loop. You really should be stopping it in `onPause()` or `onStop()`, picking it up again (if needed) in `onResume()` or `onStart()`.